# Getting correct code for Weather.com weather map

Tags: javascript, php, html, maps, weather

I want to put a weather map on my site.  I am using imagery from Weather.com's map.  One of the map images is: [image], for example (http://h1.ortho.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/h0320101.png?g=1).  I want to tile these images so they make a map.  I can do this.  But when I want to mpt the current radar image there, Weather.com updates the url every few minutes, so the link to the image changes.  So one minute the link is  http://g0.imwx.com/TileServer/imgs/radar/u1383022800000/0320100.png and the next it's http://g0.imwx.com/TileServer/imgs/radar/u1383089700000/0320100.png.
The thing that changes is the numbers in the link, for example: u1383089700000 in the image link.  I got this link from weather.com's small weather map on the "right-now" page for 21157.  Is there a way to find out what this number is when the page loads?  Right now I am just using a parameter in my site's url, then it inserts that in, but I have to find the code.

Comment: Unless Weather.com has an API for this, you could set up a Phantom script to pull the latest image.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to use some client side map as a service solution like google maps or mapbox and then hitting weather.com api to get weather data by location. Once you have this data, you can then plot it on top of the client side map again using google maps api or the mapbox api.
I hope that helps.

Manas

Comment: Weather.com API?? I have looked and looked for this and could not find it. How do you get Weather Data from weather.com? And thanks, I will try that